# YouTube intent resultCode

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to control different situations at control back on youtube intent using "YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions" the problem is that at the end of the youtube activity resultCode is ALWAYS RESULT_CANCELED.

My code:

```
public void playVideo(String s){
    Intent intent;
    intent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(this, s, true, true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_REQUEST);
}
```

Control

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) { //<-- ALLWAYS CANCELED

        Intent intent;
        intent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(this, "Hmd53MDnOjg", true, true);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Has anyone had a different result from resultCode?

Answer (score 0):

The RESULT_CANCELED resultCode is genrally due to a problem with your API_KEY.
Check with this [Google Developers tutorial](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) that you have not missed a step for a proper use of this API.

Comment: I saw the tutorial and YoutubeIntents Docs ([link]https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents#Overview[/link]) and YoutubeIntents class doesn't use API_KEY. Anyways I tryed my code on the youtube_api sample with the signed app and all things on the sample are working fine less the code that i added to the sample. That code launch the intent and intent works fine but resultCode continues RESULT_CANCELED.